# How to display soft-keyboard when edittext is get focused?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my activity there is three editText view it will randomly gets hide at some time 
After entering a single text in the editText the soft-keyboard will disappears automatically
Now I want to show the soft keyboard When editText get focused 
How to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Through `InputMethodManager` you can show and hide the soft keyboard. Use `toggleSoftInput()` method to show soft keyboard when `EditText` get focus and use `hideSoftInputFromWindow()` to hide the keyboard when `EditText` lost focus as below...

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean isFocused) {

        if (isFocused) {

            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        } else {

            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0); 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with these code..

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (inputMethodManager != null) {
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}
```